# How to flip gravity and the player in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

Does anyone know a way I could flip gravity in Roblox? Like not just gravity itself I want the one player to flip too so they can walk on the ceiling and not just float up. I tried to find how to do it but there was no answer.

Can someone help me with it please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider achieving the "gravity flip" by rotating the World Camera Axis by 180 degrees and then rotating all BaseItems by their Y-axis.

Something like this:

```
local rotation = CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(180), 0)
game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame * rotation
```

Hope this helps!